# Expected probability that $i$-th coupon is not chosen after picking $M$ coupons

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

There are $N$ distinct types of coupons in a cereal boxe and each type, independent of prior selections, is equally likely to be in a box. You draw $M$ coupons from the cereal box. What is the expected probability that the $i$-th coupon type is not among the $M$ coupons?

I am confused about the prefix "expected" in this case. The probability in this situation isn't a random variable, and isn't it simply
$$
\frac{(N - 1)^M}{N^M}
$$
?

Here's the exact problem from the book:
[image]

[image]

I already solved parts A and B. But in the hint for, the last sentence seems like a follow up question that needs to be solved, or maybe it's actually a hint for part B. I assumed it was a followup question.

Comment: In any case, I agree that the word "expected" is not clear in this context.  I assume that they just mean "find the probability that..."

Comment: @lulu Yes, I just updated it. I'm going to paste the exact problem from the book.

Comment: The hint for part $B$ is just that, a hint.  Once you know that probability $P$ you can use Linearity of Expectation to answer $B$.

Comment: @lulu Yeah, that's how I solved part B, but I just thought that was a followup question. I guess it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You’re right on both counts – it should just be “probability”, not “expected probability”, and the desired probability is $\left(\frac{N-1}N\right)^M$.